# How to set Java String with Escape Character?

Tags: java

I have a class A and I wanted to set the value to the object after that convert the same to json string using object mapper . 
The problem here is the string that I am setting has to starts with escape char (`"\"`) as shown below .
Actual value I wanted to set is `"\/Date(1457540067076-0500)\/"` .

Please provide me any guidance or example

```
A obj = new A();
obj.setTransationDateTime("\/Date(1457540067076-0500)\/");  == Compilation Problem 
obj.setTransationDateTime("\\/Date(1457540067076-0500)\\/"); == Json Object is setting value to "\\/Date(1457540067076-0500)\\/" instead of "\/Date(1457540067076-0500)\/"
```

Comment: Can we see the class definition of `A`?

Comment: Simple Class with attribute and setter & getter .

public class A{
 private String tranasactionDate;
 public String getTranasactionDate() {
  return tranasactionDate;
 }
 public void setTranasactionDate(String tranasactionDate) {
  this.tranasactionDate = tranasactionDate;
 }
  
}